# c++ boost lexical cast double to string

Tags: c++, string, boost, double

For the following piece of code

```
std::cout<<boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(2.34)<<std::endl
```

i get the following output:

```
2.3399999999999999
```

Whereas if i do

```
 double d = 2.34;
 std::stringstream ss;
 ss<<d;
 std::string s = ss.str();
 cout<<s<<endl;
```

i get the following output:

```
 2.34
```

Why is this happening ? Obviously, I am looking for the latter's output representation, and not the former.

Thanks,

Comment: @NicolBolas edited, not sure how that 1 slipped in ...

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the boost::lexical_cast, but it comes along with double's internal representation:

See this answer also:
[C++ internal representation of double/float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656947/c-internal-representation-of-double-float)

Comment: That was my initial instinct, too, but only `double`s are explicitly used here (no `float`s). See http://ideone.com/iVw2e for a demonstration.